# Smarttable stops fetching data when ID is changed

Tags: sapui5

I'm experimenting with annotations and smart controls, so I created an app from a Fiori Template and started playing with it. At some point inserted in the Object view a smart table (sap.ui.comp.smarttable) directly bound to an entity, no filters, no sorting, just fetch me all the data, something that of course worked. Things started getting interesting when I changed the table ID in the view. As soon as I did it, data stopped appearing and of course started appearing again as soon as I changed the table ID back in the old one. There are NO dependencies for this table, it's just there sitting in the view. Used the search function and scanned the entire project for the ID string, the only occurrence returned is the view definition. Any help?

Table definition snapshot below ("actionsTable" is the only string working and this is the only place found)

```
        <smartTable:SmartTable id="actionsTable" 
            smartFilterId="smartFilterBar" tableType="ResponsiveTable" entitySet="AgreementActionsSet"
            useExportToExcel="true" beforeExport="onBeforeExport" useVariantManagement="false"
            useTablePersonalisation="true" header="Line Items" showRowCount="true"
            persistencyKey="SmartTableAnalytical_Explored" enableAutoBinding="false"
            demandPopin="true" class="sapUiResponsiveContentPadding">           
            <Table>
                <ColumnListItem
                    type="Navigation"
                    press="onPress">
                </ColumnListItem>   
            </Table>
        </smartTable:SmartTable>
```

Answer (score 0):

Invalid character (not Latin) inside the name (pasted from elsewhere). Question answered, apologies to everybody spent time on it.